# calculate new table from values of old table and find fit model curve

Tags: fitting, list-manipulation

I'm new to mathematica and I'm struggling to figure this out.

I have a file with 6 space separated numerical data columns. Column 3 and 4 are the x and y values of the real data, column 5 and 6 are the correct values it should have. The errors in the real data have a radial dependency, I want to calculate radii for real and correct data, calculate the relative deviation depending on the radius and find the best fitting model curve for the deviation.

I got the data read from the file with

```
data = ReadList["/path/to/data_file.txt", {Number, Number, Number, Number, Number, Number}]
```

To my understanding the [Fit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html?q=Fit) or [FindFormula](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) functions need the data in {{x1, f1}, {x2, f2}, ...} format. However I'm failing to calculate a new table from **data** that contains calculated radius and deviation pairs; I want to do something like

```
loop over all rows of "data" with row index i:
    deviation[i] = { Sqrt[ data[i][5]^2 + data[i][6]^2 ], Sqrt[ data[i][3]^2 + data[i][4]^2 ] / Sqrt[ data[i][5]^2 + data[i][6]^2 ] }
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: And when you do `Table[deviation[i]={Sqrt[....[6]^2]},{i,Length[data]}`?

Comment: @Feyre no, because `{i, Length[data]}` will give me the row index of data as variable, however I need the radius as variable

Comment: This uses `i` is variable, and increases `i` by +1 up to `Length[data]`. Note that `[[i]]` is the `ith` element, so not `[i]`

Comment: your main issue seems to be basic syntax, mathematica uses double brackets for list items, so you should have  `data[[i,3]]`, not `data[i][3]`, then use `Table` as suggested.

Comment: This is what I've tried:

    `radius[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]

    deviation = Table[ radius[daten[[i, 5]], daten[[i, 6]]]  /  radius[daten[[i, 3]], daten[[i, 4]]], {i, Length[daten]} ]`

I get a 1 dimensional array with the relative deviations.

But what I'm looking for is a 2 dimensional table with 1 column be the radius, and the second be the relative deviation.